# AWS Cloudfront Video Streaming - Video Quality Change

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront, video-on-demand, aws-media-convert

I am developing an Video-on-demand mobile application. Videos are converted using AWS Elastic media converter and stored in S3 bucket. It will be streamed using Cloudfront.

The problem I'm facing is to stream the video on different quality(720p,360p..)

If user has less data then they wish to watch video in low quality. So how to change the video quality manually ?

Comment: did you find the answer to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the solution with Lambda@Edge and request the video resolution via GET parameters in this manner (copied from AWS Blog):

[image]

Read More [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/on-the-fly-video-conversion-amazon-cloudfront-lambdaedge-mediaconvert/) .

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that you need multiple resolution videos so user can switch the quality based on their internet connection and you are using AWS media convert.

- You need to convert the multiple resolution videos first using the trascoding services that you are using AWS then need to pass these multiple resolution files on media player so it will show the quality section features.let me know if you need more clarification or help on that.